# Clojure what does #' mean

Tags: clojure, ring

I am following this tutorial [building a Clojure backend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application)
and I'm not exactly well versed in Clojure.

The tutorial provides this source file

```
(ns shouter.web
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as ring]))

(defroutes routes
  (GET "/" [] "<h2>Hello World</h2>"))

(defn -main []
  (ring/run-jetty #'routes {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

what exactly does the `#'` mean? I know somehow it's getting the value of `routes` but why can you not just say

```
(ring/run-jetty routes {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

Is the `#'` a ring specific syntax? Couldn't find any good resources on the matter.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945187/is-pound-quote-hash-quote-in-clojure-running-the-resolve-and-symbol-functi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#'sym` expands to `(var sym)`.

A var can be used interchangeably as the function bound to it. However, invoking a var resolves the defined function dynamically and then invokes it.

In this case it serves development purposes: Instead of passing the handler function `routes` by value, the var it is bound to is passed so that Jetty does not have to be restarted after you change and re-evaluate `shouter.web/routes`.