# Value of a list with quoted first argument in clojure is the last argument?

Tags: clojure

Why does the expression

```
('+ 10 20)
```

evaluate to `20`? This is realy bizarre to me! I would have expected to give an error, because the first element of the list, `'+` i not a thing that can be evaluated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty much an FAQ with Clojure, for good or bad. So `'+` is shorthand for `(quote +)` which evaluates to the symbol `+`. Symbols (and keywords) can be treated as functions and look themselves up in their argument, so `('+ 10 20)` is essentially `(get 10 '+ 20)` and that's the `not-found` arity of `get` so if the "collection" `10` does not include the symbol `'+` then it will return the third argument, `20`.

You might expect associative lookup against `10` to fail and throw an exception but there are a lot of situations in Clojure where lookup will return `nil` (or the `not-found` version) because it's beneficial from a `nil`-punning point of view and is part of what leads to idiomatic Clojure.

Some functions *do* perform that sort of argument checking: `(contains? 10 '+)` will throw an exception, for example, whereas both `(get 10 '+)` and `(get '+ 10)` will both return `nil`.

It's probably also worth noting that the following throws an exception:

```
user=> ('+ 10 20 30)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval39476 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (3) passed to: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

You asked if the "value of a list with quoted first argument in clojure is the last argument" and the answer is no, this is very specifically a two-argument function invocation, because of the above logic: you can't "call" a symbol with 3 args, only with 1 or 2.

Worth noting the difference here for the 0 args case:

```
user=> ('+)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval39478 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.Symbol
user=> (+)
0
```

The first case is a symbol lookup -- which requires at least a collection to look itself up in -- whereas the second case is a function invocation (of `clojure.core/+`) with zero arguments, which returns the identity value of `+` in the same way that `(*)` returns `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation.  I had no idea.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. Is this written down somewhere in the docs (an FAQ section, perhaps?)

Comment: Official docs: https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Symbols